# Using $sum to add up all the values of a two objects with arrays in Mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

I'm trying to get the sum of the second items in each array in each object. For ex:

```
items: 
- 0 {
     "key": "Reservations",
   - "values": 
      [date, amount],
      [date, amount],
      [date, amount]
    },
- 1 {
     "key": "Non-reservations",
   - "values": 
      [date, amount],
      [date, amount],
      [date, amount]
    },
```

I'm trying to use $sum to add up all the "amounts" in both objects.

Edit for @NeilLunn:
Here is an output that comes close to what I am trying to access:

Input

```
db.reservations.aggregate([ { "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 }, "Helm": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$source", "Helm" ] }, 1, 0] } }, "Consumer": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$source", "Consumer" ] }, 1, 0] } } } } ] )
```

Output

```
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 155, "Helm" : 43, "Consumer" : 2 }
```

I want to sum up the total of Helm and Consumer.

Comment: That's not Mongo shell output, or really a valid representation of a document. Please show the documents as they appear in the MongoDB shell.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I know. It's the look of what I am trying to access. The output is just a normal JSON. What I am demonstrating is how it shows up in ARC.

Comment: @NeilLunn, please take a look at my edit.

Comment: We need the original document and not just your output. By all means also show what you are doing for the output, but the important thing here is the actual original document. Not just a sketch of what "you think" represents the layout.

Comment: So show it from the mongo shell. Your question uses "mongo shell" in the title. So you should be using it. We cannot support every arcane tool on the market.